# Node: How to ensure a function runs ONLY after an object has been created?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `nodejs` with `cheerio` to scrape data from a website, and it creates an object from it. Then, it needs to take that object and use it in a function.

The issue is, my object is being created but before `cheerio` can properly parse the data and put it into the object, the next function is already running. Here's my code:

```
function getInfo(obj, link){
    request(link, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Uh-oh: " + err);
            throw err;
        }
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        function createProduct(obj, callback){
            var product = {
                    name        : $('#name').text(),
                    gender      : obj.gender,
                    infoLink    : link,
                    designer    : $('.label').first().text(),
                    price       : $('#price').first().text(),
                    description : $('.description').text(),
                    date        : new Date()
            }
           product.systemName = (function(){
            return product.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
           }());

            callback(product);
        }
        createProduct(obj, function(product){
            lookUp(product);
        });
```

I'm getting mixed results here. Some `product` objects are being sent to the function just fine with all the details properly input. Some are missing descriptions, others are missing every `cheerio`-populated content. Others have some `cheerio` scraped content, but are missing certain bits. The `gender` and `date` attributes are always there, and the properties exist, but they're just blank (e.g. `product.name` returns `""` rather than undefined).

I've checked each offending link and all pages contain the correct selectors to be scraped.

How can I set up the callback to ONLY function once the `product` object has been populated?

Comment: I don't know cheerio, but it looks like the `cherio.load(body)` function is asynchron. I'm not sure if this is true, but if it is, you have to specify a callback for load. Check the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible asynchronous executions which can get you these results :

1. `cheerio.load` has not finished before `createProduct` is called.
2. In `createProduct` `product` is not getting populated or partially like description before `callback` is called (not sure).

You can use [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async) library to make functions execute synchronously (by using `async.series`). If `createProduct` is asynchronous as well , you will have to make it synchronous in similar way.

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        createProduct(obj, function(product){
            lookUp(product);
        });
        callback();
    }
]);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the callbacks are working in your example? I'm trying to work with this code but it seems like `$` isn't being passed from the first function to the next. For instance, if I want to put `createProduct` as a function in the middle of those two functions, how do I return the `product` to the last callback?

Comment: Scratch everything, got it working by declaring `product = {}` before `async.series` was called. Cheers!